# PL/SQL - Oracle based function to get content of all varibles during runtime

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle11g, exception

I want to improve our exception handling. In case of an exception it would be good to have more than the error message, the error backtrace or error callstack.

We work with dynamic SQL, and for me it would be an improvement if I could log all Input and Output variables, and the content of the dynamic SQLStatement in each exception of the code.

Sure I can seperately address each variable and log them with the data content like in this example:

```
exception
   when others then
        cg$errors.log_new (null,null,'Test-Unit',null,'SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE || chr(10) 
            || ' --- SQLERRM: ' || sqlerrm || chr(10)
            || ' --- Stacktrace: ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace  || chr(10)
            || ' --- Parameter:'|| chr(10)
            || 'vWorkstation in Varchar2: ' || vWorkstation || chr(10)
            || 'vUser in Varchar2: ' || vUser || chr(10)
            || 'vtest clob : ' || vtest|| chr(10)
            || 'vtest1 clob : ' || vtest1|| chr(10)
            || 'vtest1m clob : ' || vtest1m|| chr(10)
            || 'temp_table clob : ' || temp_table|| chr(10));
  raise;
```

But this is high-maintenance, because I need to explicitly address different variables (`vWorkstation`, `vUser` and so on) in each exception.

When I run a PL/SQL unit in Debug Mode I can see a list of all variables (vWorkstation, vUser, and so on) with each step I debug the code. So I think when the SQL developer shows me this data during debugging there must be a way to get a list of the variables during runtime.

So I thought if there is a function or procedure embedded by Oracle, that I can call and which returns all variables used in the code with their names an their content this would be great. I would like to call this function in each of my tougher exceptions.

Do you know such a Oracle function?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Its better to use the way your code uses to dump needed variables instead of all the variables.
I thought I must share my opinion unless you have a specific purpose to log/dump all he variables at that moment.
Thanks

Comment: Your logging procedure can figure out the call and error stack details itself. I wouldn't bother with `sqlcode` as it's already part of the error stack. As for the complete list of variables in scope, PL/SQL doesn't have this kind of introspection.

Answer (score 0):

IDEs such as PL/SQL Developer have a built-in debug capability (which is what I think you mean by *"run a PL/SQL unit in Debug Mode"*). This is a framework built over an Oracle built-in package [DBMS_DEBUG](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_debug.htm#ARPLS66167). This is very much a toolbox, rather than a working tool. The most important thing to bear in mind is that the debugger runs in a **separate session** which probes the running code. This means it's not suitable for your purpose.

Logging long lists of variables and parameters is a bit of a nause, and maintaining them a matter of discipline. But alas there's no better option.